# Strange behavior using workaround to refrain device from sleeping with App Inventor 2

Tags: android, sleep, app-inventor, video-player

I'm using [this](http://puravidaapps.com/countdown.php) workaround, to refrain device from sleeping in App Inventor 2, but I noticed a strange behavior on device.

First of all, the under development app, is a one screen application with a ListPicker component and some timers. When the user makes a pick, the screen returns in Screen1 as it should, but with the VideoPlayer controller buttons showing up for a second, and they shouldn't be visible (is tested on a Gingerbread 2.6.3. device).

What is more, the app is refrained from sleep only when no clock timers are set on and for about 10 min period, and I need it to stay refrained for up to 3 hours in intervals.

Does anyone know a solution to this strange VideoPlayer behavior, or a better sleeping refrain approach in App Inventor 2?

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Did you set the video player size to width x height = 1x1? Further workarounds also are mentioned [on that page](https://puravidaapps.com/countdown.php), for example the notifier workaround. However generally App Inventor apps can't run in the background. There is also [this solution](https://puravidaapps.com/alarmmanager.php).

Comment: Hi Taifun. Yes of cource I've tested with both 1x1 px video player and with the simple txt notifier. My question still is, why video controls are displayed on Screen1 return from ListPicker?